# How to change the {{ }} thingys in angular js? to [{ }]

Tags: angularjs

I know there is some way to change the ng-binding thingys {{ expression }} to {[ expression ]} because I've done it before but I don't remember what the thingys are called.. so I don't know how to look it up. I can't find it in the angular docs.

Help please!

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: "braces"=="curly braces", "brackets"=="square brackets", "parentheses"=="round parentheses"=="round brackets"(less common in my experience)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `$interpolateProvider`

```
angular.module('myApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
            $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[{');
            $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]');
  });
```